# Is there anyway to change sort_link output params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, parameters, meta-search

I wanna make a page that contains more than one tables. Each table is ajax filtered table that can be sorted using metasearch. This is sorting link for each table. 
Controller SomeController:

```
def index
  @search = FirstTable.search(params[:search])
  @first_tables = @search.all

  @search_second_table = SecondTable.search(params[:search_second_table])
  @second_tables = @search_second_table.all

  ...
end
```

View:

```
# First table
sort_link @search, :some_attribute, "Some Attribute"
#=> www.example.com/some_controller?search[meta_sort]=some_attribute.asc

# Second table
sort_link @search_second_table, :some_attribute, "Some Attribute"
#=> www.example.com/some_controller?search[meta_sort]=some_attribute.asc
```

I have no idea why the sort_link outputting the same link or maybe I've made some mistake. Is there anyway to change the output of second_table sort_link to be like this.

```
#=> www.example.com/some_controller?search_second_table[meta_sort]=some_attribute.asc
```

Thx for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solved my problem using `link_to`. after click "Some Attribute" link, change the "meta_sort" params to desc using jquery, right after ajax response return successfully. `link_to "Some Attribute", :controller => "some_controller", :search_second_table => {:meta_sort => "some_attribute.asc"}`